# converting 'malformed' java json object to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, parsing

I have a Java JSON Object, its format is [{a=b}], I am trying to pass this object into javascript as a JSON object but its missing " on both the key and value as well as having "=" instead of ":"

Is there a simple way of converting this JAVA JSON object to be consumable by different services?

Parsing is proving to be very complicated as the actual JSON is nested and the lack of quotations and the lacking of indications for nestedness.

Sample of 'JSON' data:

[{wwnType=Virtual, serialNumberType=Virtual, connections=[], modified=2016-10-29T19:00:04.457Z, macType=Virtual, category=server-profile-templates, serverHardwareTypeUri=/rest/server-hardware-types/32006464-D3C6-4B4E-8328-47A193C6116C, bios={overriddenSettings=[], manageBios=false}, firmware={firmwareBaselineUri=null, manageFirmware=false, forceInstallFirmware=false, firmwareInstallType=null}, boot={manageBoot=true, order=[CD, Floppy, USB, HardDisk, PXE]}, hideUnusedFlexNics=true, bootMode=null, state=null, affinity=Bay, localStorage={controllers=[]}, type=ServerProfileTemplateV1, status=OK, description=, eTag=1477767604457/1, serverProfileDescription=test, name=test, created=2016-10-29T19:00:04.428Z, enclosureGroupUri=/rest/enclosure-groups/e989621b-930e-40e7-9db0-a6ddbf841709, uri=/rest/server-profile-templates/db1dbdcc-4237-4452-acc3-cf9dfdc75365, sanStorage={manageSanStorage=false, volumeAttachments=[]}}]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be simple.  However, I think you can do this without writing a full-fledged parser, as long as you're willing to write a tokenizer, or lexical analyzer, to break your input string into tokens.  The basic plan could be something like:

1. Convert your input into a list of tokens.  I don't know what the format of your input is, so you'll need to do your own analysis.  A token would be something like a single character `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, comma, `=`; or an identifier (`a` or `b` in your example, but I don't know what the possible valid formats are); or, maybe, a string literal in quotes, or a numeric literal, depending on what your needs are.
2. Go through the string and replace the tokens you need to.  Based on your example, I'd say that after a `{`:  if the first token after that is an identifier, put it in quotes; if the second token after that is `=`, change it to `:`; if the third token after that is an identifier, put it in quotes.  The same could be true after a comma, but you'll need to keep track of whether the comma is a separator for a list of key-value pairs in an object, or a list of values in an array.  For that, you may need to keep a stack that you push whenever you see `[` or `{`, and pop whenever you see `}` or `]`, so that you know whether you're inside an object or an array.
3. After you're done replacing everything, concatenate the tokens back together.  The result should be a well-formed JSON object.

This is just a rough outline, since I really don't know all your requirements.  You'll probably have to adapt this answer to meet your exact needs.  But I hope this helps as a general idea of how you could approach the problem.

Sorry, I don't think there's a simpler answer, except that you might want to look into parser generators (see [Yacc equivalent for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639512/yacc-equivalent-for-java)).  I haven't actually looked at any in Java, so I don't know how simple they are to use.  Please don't try to solve the whole thing with regexes.  (Regexes will be useful for breaking your string into tokens, but trying to do more than that with regexes is likely to produce nothing but migraine.)

Answer (score 0):

I think isn't json object. json object should be like this.

Example:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("a", "b");
obj.put("name", "your name");
```

Output: {"a": "b", "name":"your name"}

Passing into javascript

```
var obj = '{"a": "b", "name":"your name"}',
var json = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.